# MochaJS: How to share assertion/"it('should')" code between tests

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have some mocha tests I run with Nodejs to test a web server.

Many of the tests should cause the server to return an error, e.g. 400 Bad Request.

Currently the tests are peppered with many copies of the following code:

```
it('should respond with 400 (Bad Request)', function (){
    expect(httpResponse.statusCode).to.equal(httpstatus.BAD_REQUEST);
});
```

Here's a simplified pseudocode example:

```
describe('When passing bad JSON data', function(){
    var response
    before(function(done){
        callUrlToInsert(url, badJson, function(err, resp){
            response = resp
            done()
        }
    }
    it('should respond with 400 (Bad Request)', function (){
        expect(httpResponse.statusCode).to.equal(httpstatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    })
}
```

This bugs me because as a programmer I avoid duplicate code wherever possible.

However, putting this into a function does not work:

```
function verifyItReturnedBadRequest400(httpResponse)
{
    it('should respond with 400 (Bad Request)', function (){
        expect(httpResponse.statusCode).to.equal(httpstatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    });
}
```

because the call to `it()` doesn't test the assertion right then; my [limited] understanding is that `it()` adds the closure to the list of tests. So by the time that check is done, the `httpResponse` variable has gone out of scope. (I don't understand why that is the case, because in both cases there is a call to it(); why would it matter that in one case it's inside another level of function call? I'm probably missing something with regard to Javascript scoping.)

**Is there a common way to avoid all this duplicate code? Or is everyone out there duplicating all their assertion code everywhere?** This is my first foray into Mocha so I am probably missing something obvious.

Also, bonus points for explaining **why doesn't the function approach work?**

Thanks!

Comment: There is something called as hooks in mocha. Which will the block before, after, beforeeach and aftereach. But I am not sure whether these hooks are capable of running test or not.

Comment: My impression is that hooks are for setup and teardown, but that checking the results must be done in the actual test. But I could be wrong. Would it make sense to put it('should') in an "after" hook?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Hooks are mainly used for setup but as of now I do not see any other option only if hooks support running test. I would suggest to give it try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your code looks something like this:

```
describe('When passing bad JSON data', function(){
    var response
    before(function(done){
        callUrlToInsert(url, badJson, function(err, resp){
            response = resp
            done()
        }
    }
    verifyItReturnedBadRequest400(httpResponse)
}
```

Think about it like this:

1. `it()` creates a test.
2. All the calls to `it` happen **before** any tests are actually run (you have to create tests before you run them)
3. The function passed to `before' is run after the tests have been created, but **before** they are run.
4. `verifyItReturnedBadRequest400` calls `it`, to create a test, but you're passing in httpResponse right then before any tests have run, so `before` hasn't run yet either.

You could continue to use that sort of pattern, but you'll need to put the httpresponse in a container so you can pass a reference to it:

```
describe('When passing bad JSON data', function(){
    var data = {};
    before(function(done){
        callUrlToInsert(url, badJson, function(err, resp){
            data.response = resp
            done()
        }
    }
    verifyItReturnedBadRequest400(data)
}
```

and then your `verifyItReturnedBadRequest400` becomes:

```
function verifyItReturnedBadRequest400(data) {
    it('should respond with 400 (Bad Request)', function (){
        expect(data.response.statusCode).to.equal(httpstatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and the link! Not only did you explain what was happening, you provided a working solution AND a link describing the industry standard for this scenario. So setting `response` after calling `it()` doesn't affect the variable that was passed in to `it`, but passing a reference to a container allows me to update the container to hold the response after the call to `it()`.

Answer (score 3):

There is an article on wiki about this.
https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Shared-Behaviours

I guess you have some bugs in your test. Placing `it()` into wrapper function works fine. Here's a small working demo.

```
'use strict';

const assert = require('assert');

const xEqualsOne = () => {
  it('should be equal 1', () => {
    assert.equal(this.x, 1);
  });
};

describe('async number', () => {
  this.x = 0;

  before(done => {
    this.x++
    setTimeout(done, 100);
  });

  xEqualsOne();
});
```

Comment: Your test works because you are not passing any parameters into xEqualsOne, so it's testing a global variable. I'd prefer not to use globals like that. But it's on the right track; see @N3dst4's answer for a deeper explanation. It's similar to yours but declares the test data within the `describe` context.

Comment: Actually, your code matches what the Mocha wiki suggests: storing data in the `this` context. So, +1.